# getting the path of the downloads folder in windows java

Tags: java, windows

i need to find the path of the downloads folder in the computer my software is running, i can't do something like "user\downloads" because the software might run on a computer that have a different language and then the folder name wouldn't be downloads.

i thought i could use windows registry or something like that but i haven't found an entry in there that says the path of the downloads folder.

i can also  choose in what programming language i write my software to any other programming language(such as c,python or c#) if it will have a better solution.

note:it will run only on windows systems.

how can i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070299/get-the-windows-download-folders-path

Comment: Why do you need that particular directory? The user can change that directory and have it be different for each browser, if they want... it seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/251060)

Comment: i need that particular directory because my client asked me to make a software that will deletes duplicate files in his downloads directory and he can barely operate a pc

Answer (score 2):

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
home = home + "\Download";
```