# how to run powershell script through excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I am trying to use an Excel VBA macro to launch a PowerShell script if a certain condition is met. I'm not getting any errors in the code when it runs and I am able to manually run the PowerShell script from the Windows Explorer window without errors. However, when I execute the below VBA code, the PowerShell does not run and I am not sure why.

```vb
Dim x as Variant
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
    x = Shell("POWERSHELL.exe " & "H:\MyFolder\MyFile.ps1", 1)
End If
```

I can't tell if something in the VBA code is wrong because I'm not getting any run time errors but the PowerShell script is not actually running

**UPDATE**: with the extra quotes I am able to see the error message now that's popping up in the cmd window but it is still having issues with the space even with the extra quotes. I have moved my script to a different file path that doesn't have spaces but I now seeing errors that running scripts are disabled. This seems like it is no longer a code based problem. thank you all!

Comment: Is PS execution policy allowing PS1 scripts to run? Default is to block execution. Try adding the `-noexit` switch if the PS1 window immediately closes.

Comment: I tried and that did not help, I see the window pop open but then closes and the script isn't executed.  I did the below: `x = Shell("POWERSHELL.exe -noexit" & "H:\Operations\REPORTS\Reports2018\Balance Sheet\SLmarginJE.ps1", 1)`

Comment: You can [edit] your question with any additional relevant info / what you've tried.

Comment: `...-noexit" & "H:\Operations\...`  you haven't left a space between these arguments

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your file path has spaces you need to put quotes around it.

```
x = Shell("POWERSHELL.exe -noexit " & _
           """H:\Operations\REPORTS\Reports2018\Balance Sheet\SLmarginJE.ps1""", 1)
```

Comment: at a command prompt, `-noexit` causes command window to remain at PS prompt after executing. Excluding `-noexit` returns to normal command-prompt. I don't understand your usage.

Comment: @johnywhy - not my usage - that's from the OP

Comment: OP seems to have removed `-noexit`. Even if they hadn't removed it, if it's in your answer then that seems to indicate that you agree with it.

Comment: It's in a comment of theirs below the question.