# MS Access Error 91 Object Variable or With block variable not set on line 0

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a button on a form with the code below sitting in the form. It used to execute without a problem. Suddenly when clicking the button I now get this run time error:

> Run-time error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set in procedure cmdImportEDD_Click, line 0

I have tried commenting out individual lines in the code to find the problem. I ended up determening that the FileDialog part seems to be a problem somehow. However, after having added the `If.. then` part to it last time, the code worked again, but today the error is back.

To be clear, the  error appears before the VBA code is executed (hence line 0) and Compile yields no errors either!

**What is happening here that I'm not getting?**

```
Private Sub cmdImportEDD_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdImportEDD_Click_Error

Dim fDialog As FileDialog
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
fDialog.InitialFileName = GetDownloadFolder
fDialog.Show
If fDialog.SelectedItems.Count < 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Debug.Print fDialog.SelectedItems(1)

'Replace the selected file with the current one
Dim sOldFile As String
sOldFile = strTARGET_EDD_SALESFILE
Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject
Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject
oFSO.DeleteFile sOldFile
oFSO.MoveFile Source:=fDialog.SelectedItems(1), Destination:=sOldFile

'Perform the update
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_app_EDD", acViewNormal, acAdd
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
MsgBox "The data has been successfully imported!", vbOKOnly Or vbInformation, "Import Data: EDD"

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

cmdImportEDD_Click_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure cmdImportEDD_Click, line " & Erl & "."
End Sub
```

The code for GetDownloadFolder:

```
Function GetDownloadFolder() As String
    Dim objShell
    Dim objFolder
    Dim objFolderItem
    Dim temp
    Const DESKTOP = &H10&

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(DESKTOP)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    temp = objFolderItem.Path
    temp = Left(temp, Len(temp) - 7) & "Downloads" '<--- I believe this is the download folder
    GetDownloadFolder = temp
End Function
```

Having canceled out the OnError I now get a debug error on the line `Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self`

Comment: For now I only have questions about `strTARGET_EDD_SALESFILE` and `GetDownloadFolder`. Is it set somewhere?

Comment: Strange behavior so far. Did you try to **de**compile/compact the database?

Comment: Remove `On Error GoTo cmdImportEDD_Click_Error` to find out which line is failing, `Erl` won't work without line numbers.

Comment: I removed the OnError... I now get the Error located in the GetDownloadFolder function. The problem seems to be that that `objFolder` turns out to be nothing in the Local Window

Comment: `Self` is not a property of Shell folder object. If you set Shell library and used early binding, then intellisense popup would trigger. However, I don't get compile error on that line.

Comment: I got run-time error on DESKTOP line. Had to put DESKTOP in quote marks. Now Self line has run-time error. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070299/get-the-windows-download-folders-path

Comment: I adjusted to early binding... you  are right, there is no `.Self`. Odd thing is that this worked in the past?!? I now also get the run time error on the DESKTOP

Comment: When was the 'past'? Did you upgrade Access and/or convert from ADP? Seems I've read that Namespace was used with Access 2003 and earlier ADP files and may no longer be supported.

Comment: It's beginning to look like this is an issue with 64BIT installation. I use two computers. One 32BIT installation of Office and the other 64BIT. I have mainly been using this  DB on the 32BIT one... this  specific function I would have used on both computers at some point though.

Comment: I posted an answer. Thanks to BrackNiku and June7 who helped me in pinpointing the problem. If either one of you want to post an answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get my code working by replacing the somewhat more complicated Shell call in the `GetDownloadFolder` function with a simpler`Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads"`.

This has taken care of the run time error.